# MySQL Syntax Error with wpdb query/prepare

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, wordpress

I'm simply trying to run a query using wpdb query and prepare statements.

On my page it returns:

> [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'myQuery' at line 1]

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    $dirName1 = 'C:/wamp/www/c2c/wp-content/themes/flawless-v1-01';
    $dirName2 = 'C:/wamp/www/c2c';
    require_once($dirName1.'/config/setup.php');
    require_once($dirName2.'/wp-config.php');
    require_once($dirName2.'/wp-load.php');

    $wpdb->show_errors();
    $tableName = $wpdb->prefix . "user_orders";
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $userId = $user->ID;
    $userName = $user->user_login;
    // echo $tableName . ':  ' . $userId . ': '. $userName; 
    // echo var_dump($tableName); 
    // echo var_dump($userId); 
    // echo var_dump($userName); 
    // These echo the correct formats for the prepare statement below
    $myQuery = $wpdb->query(
        $wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT * 
            FROM $tableName 
            WHERE `user_id` = %d 
            AND `user_name` = %s", 
            $tableName, 
           $userId, 
        $userName)
    );
    $results = $wpdb->get_results(myQuery, ARRAY_A);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the dollar sign before your variable name:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results(myQuery, ARRAY_A);
```

should be

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($myQuery, ARRAY_A);
```